# How to access a value in an hiera hash directly with puppet lookup?

Tags: puppet, hiera

Let's say there is an hiera hash:

```
foo::bar:
  key1: 'value1'
  key2: 'value2'
```

Is there any possibility to lookup the value of `key1` directly with the lookup function?

I thought of something like:

```
class myclass (
  String $value1 = lookup('foo::bar::key1'),
) {
...
}
```

The only way I could solve this, is to lookup the Hash and acces the value later with `hash['key1']`, but maybe there is a more clean way to do this.

Comment: The closest you could achieve this with is: `lookup('foo::bar')['key1']`

Comment: You can now use `lookup('foo::bar.key1')` in puppet6 https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/hiera_automatic.html#access_hash_array-elements_keysubkey_notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do this in Puppet using just `lookup`.

Fundamentally, `lookup` works by looking up Hiera keys, which are unrelated to hash keys. A Hiera key of the form `foo::bar::baz` is effectively a single unstructured string - it doesn't imply that there are hashes called `foo` or `foo::bar`. The `::` is just part of the key string - it isn't syntactic sugar for a hash lookup, as is, for example, `.` in JavaScript.

`lookup` is documented at

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/hiera_automatic.html

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible in puppet (v6 and later)!  You use dot notation

`lookup('foo::bar.key1')`

See the puppet documentation here: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/hiera_automatic.html#access_hash_array-elements_keysubkey_notation